# How to connect to a Remote Database from native Iphone app

Tags: iphone

I want to connect to a remote database(MySQL or SQL Server or Oracle) via internet from my native iphone app.  I can't find any API or Framework in System to add.  does any one know how to connect to a remote Database?  pleased help me.  Thank you very much

Comment: This question is very close to these others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947835/iphone-connecting-to-database-over-internet , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249416/iphone-networking , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373011/what-is-the-best-way-of-connecting-to-a-remote-server-database-to-retrieve-data-f , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451428/iphone-sqlite-db-and-web-based-db-synchronization-and-interaction-recommendations

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an iPhone programmer, but I would suspect you want some abstraction going on.

Instead of trying to make a native database connection work, consider writing some service layer that talks to the database on the back-end, and speaks HTTP to your client application.

Plenty of very good reasons for this.  Security concerns chief among them.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to setup an HTTPS server that wraps your requests.  Submit your queries via HTTPS POST.  The server setup would be pretty basic and it gives you the chance to do any post-processing before sending it over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative is to use webservices to access the information stored remotely.

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : Shamelessly plugging my own product :)

We've built an online system called Kumulos that allows iOS and OSX developers to build and host online databases in the cloud, while easily creating custom API methods for accessing it. It even builds all the Objective-C bindings for you.

Its really really easy to use and its free while in Beta. We'd love some honest developer feedback :)

Check it out [here](http://www.kumulos.com)