# Develop an iOS App that gets contents from a remote DB

Tags: mysql, database, ios

I am developing an education app for Kids. 
The application is going to contain pictures, stories and video as well.
Including all above contents in the app will surely bloat it and hence i would like store all data on a server that will be accessed by my app.

I haven't used any remote databases (like MySQL or Oracle) with any other iOS app. In fact i am a newbie in developing such kind of apps. Can any one point me to a sample

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417134/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-database-from-native-iphone-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to a remote mysql is really not recommended.
The security here is critical.

You should create a webservice and my advice to you is to make sure that the access to the webservice is restricted

The webservice can be your own "protocol" or any other well known protocol like SOAP

By your own I mean, json, csv .... or whatever.

**Edit 1**

The technology of your webservice should be dependent on many things.
If the system is small, and the code needs to be update very often, I would suggest to do it with PHP and some small(!) MVC framework  like CI.

But if its a large system with needs of ACL (access control list)  I will probably choose java with spring...

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestion as to whether Java+Glass Fish/Tomcat will be more preferred for creating my Web Service OR PHP and it's APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that : Do not connect to / use database directly from user application. It may causes serious security problems and your app should have native SQL drivers to connect db.

So, create a web service that receive queries from the application and response in XML, JSON or some other strings that easy to parse. This will be much easier than embed native APIs into your apps.