# iPhone SDK: Data Synchronization

Tags: sql, iphone, sqlite

I am looking for an overview of data synchronization techniques available on the iPhone platform. We need the ability to be able to sync a subset of content from a server to a local database residing on the iPhone.

On other projects I have worked on, the data synchronization was handled by the database. Is that available in SQLite? If not, any suggestions on techniques? Rolling our own would not be my first choice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there's currently a tool/feature that does this.  A similar question was posted, which links to an article how someone rolled their own.

In essence, you could create a "pending" queue table that kept track of the record id's that needed to be updated.  When the app needed to synch, as long as you had a way to identify the local record with the server record it could synch it that way.  And of course the opposite way from the server down.

[iPhone SQLite DB and Web-based DB synchronization and interaction recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451428/iphone-sqlite-db-and-web-based-db-synchronization-and-interaction-recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

There is one framework that could help you if you are using Core Data.

You shall have a look at ZSync. An overview is available here:
http://ideveloper.tv/freevideo/details?index=17089146

If you are using SQLite I strongly suggest that you consider switching to Core Data. You will certainly gain some performances and the integration of undo/redo.

You'll have to remove a whole bunch of custom code anyway... :)